# Advanced Calculus Book for Computer Science Student

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I study Computer Science, but our mathematic coures are a little bit to basic.

I'm looking for a "advanced Calculus" book for self-study that has a lot of exercises. The book should focus on explaining and not just containing a bunch of formulas.

what I already have learnt:

- Matrices
- Matrix transformation (e.g. Scale, Rotation, Translation and so on)
- Vector calculation in $\mathfrak{R}^2$ / $\mathfrak{R}^3$ (Cross Product, Dot Product, Projection and so on)
- Homogeneous coordinates
- plane / sphere / line equation
- derivation with one variable
- integration
- number series
- limit
- Complex Numbers / Quaternion (only rotation)
- basic in discrete Mathematics

what I especially want to learn:

- vector analysis
- multivariable integration/derivation
- Integral equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am rather interested in acquiring this book

http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich1.pdf

and the 2nd volume

http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich2.pdf

These two books are quite thorough, and rigorous, and go all the way from the (modern) foundations of calculus in $\mathbb{R}$, to discussing differential forms and their integration over suitable manifolds (a significant generalization of even multivariable calculus).

Edit: Links appear to be dead now...

Comment: The links do not work.

Comment: Those links used to work, but I guess they no longer do...

Comment: It was a violation of copyright, no wonder they disappeared. But I recommend those books too. For more information: [volume 1](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662487907) and [volume 2](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662489918).

Answer (score 2):

This book is online, and may be of use to you. It was apparently used at Harvard, and the material may be up to your standards of sophistication.
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. Nice book (and even nicer that it's on one of the authors' sites, so presumably perfectly legal rather than a pirated copy). Might not be exactly what the op's looking for -- sounds to me like he maybe wants a book that would be used in the engineering school rather than the math department.

Answer (score 1):

Let me recommend [Corral's Vector Calculus](http://mecmath.net/). 
The book is short and good, altho I would not call it "advanced".
In addition it is written under free license ([GFDL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl.html)).

I used it to teach Vector Calculus at Penn State and made some minor changes which available [here](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/calc3book/).